# i have imported everything but still it throws this error TypeError: can't access property "url", postDetails is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

when i imported postDetails in another component it says postDetails is undefined

```
import {createContext, useState} from 'react'


export const PostContext = createContext(null)

function Post({children}){

    const [postDetails, setPostDetails] = useState('')


    return(
        <PostContext.Provider value={ postDetails , setPostDetails } >
          {children}
        </PostContext.Provider>
    )

}

export default Post
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value accepts an object (particularly one thing, same as all other props), wrap your value in an object. see value on `PostContext.Provider` line:

```
 return(
        <PostContext.Provider value={{ postDetails , setPostDetails }} >
          {children}
        </PostContext.Provider>
    )
```

Comment: i  used it like this   const {postDetails} = useContext(PostContext)  do i have to change anything in this

Comment: no that's okay, because it returns the same object